# Polling an API with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, polling

I need to poll an API for a response every 30 seconds in React

I was thinking of calling this method:

```js
poll() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('polling') // would hit the API here
    }, 100)
}
```

inside `componentDidMount` and then doing a ternary inside it or something

but in `componentDidMount` it doesn't like me doing this

`this.props.loading ? this.poll() : null`

saying something about expected function but saw expression (linting error)

how can I poll the API or is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: please share complete code with life cycle and constructor function

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the *props.loading* inside the *poll()* method, this way:

```
poll () {
    // you should keep track of the timeout scheduled and 
    // provide a cleanup if needed
    this.state.polling && clearTimeout(this.state.polling)

    if (!this.props.loading) {            
        this.setState({ polling: false })
        return
    }

    const polling = setTimeout(() => {
        // stuff here

        // as last step you should call poll() method again
        // if you have asyncronous code you should not call it
        // as a step of your async flow, as it has already is 
        // time period with setTimeout
        this.poll()
    }
    , this.state.pollingIntervall)

    this.setState({
        polling
    })
}
```

Then you just need to call the *poll()* method to start it.

Had added the *state.pollingIntervall* just to allow the time of polling to be configured.